# .dot-prefixed directories in NuGet packages?

Tags: nuget, teamcity, nuget-package, nuspec, nuget-spec

Currently I have a bunch of files living in a directory under TFS. Essentially I want to make a NuGet package out of it in my build server.

I do want however to move the file structure into a sub-directory and re-base from there. Let me explain:

The TFS path watched is: `$/Foo/Bar/`

```
$/Foo/Bar/
│
│   Bar.nuspec
│
└───PackageContent/
    │   GenPumpGraphCtrl.dll
    │   MultiPumpCurve.dll
    │   PumpGraphCtrl2.dll
    │
    ├───Dwg/
    │       Logofnt1.wmf
    │       LOGOFNT1a.wmf
    │       LOGOFNT1b.wmf
    │
    ├───Ref/
    │       AqSolutions.xbn
    │       Astring.bin
    │       WordTranslation.xbn
    │
    └───Temp/
        │   
        └───Notes/
                Notes.txt
```

My .nuspec uses:

```
  <files>
    <file src="PackageContent\**"/>
  </files>
```

However, I want to rename the `PackageContent` directory to `.package-content` and updated my .nuspec:

```
  <files>
    <file src=".package-content\**"/>
  </files>
```

But by NuGet Pack step in TeamCity complains with the following error:

```
>> Cannot create a package that has no dependencies nor content.
```

1. Are `.dot-prefixed` directories somewhat hidden from TFS?
2. Are `.dot-prefixed` directories automatically ignored by the some obscure rule in the .nuspec?

---

**Further investigation into the problem shows that in fact, if I place any `.dot-prefixed` directory, it gets entirely excluded from my NuGet package, despite using a wildcard.**

**The question is clearer now: How can I ensure I really include everything? Including `.dot-prefixed` directories?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, in fact there is this obscure `-NoDefaultExcludes` parameter for `nuget pack`.

In my case, I had to add it to the Command line parameters box for the TeamCity NuGet Pack step:

[image]

Comment: this answer is a hidden gem